If $ \det(A) = 1 $ then the minors of the principal submatrices of the matrix $ B:= P^T A S $ are all equal to $1$
Let $A$ be an $N \times N$ matrix such that $\det(A) = 1$. How can we prove that there exists a permutation matrix $P$ and a vector $s \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, whose $N$-th element is $0$, such that the minors of the principal submatrices of the matrix $B := P^T A S$ are all equal to $1$?
Here, $ S = I + e_N s $, where $ e_N $ is the $ N $-th column of the identity matrix.

Use $$ as the mathjax environment instead of \ ( \ )
